# First the next and previous cells with data in a row Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to write code that will look at the first cell to the left, and the first cell to the right of the cell in question, and return those cells' column number values. The code that I have currently uses the `.Find` method, and it is only returning the cells immediately to the right/left of the cell in question. From the screenshot, if I am in cell `G2` in my loop, I want to return column 4 and column 9 for `iFirst` and `iLast` respectively.  I am actually returning 6 and 8.  What is wrong?  Here is my code:

```
Public iLastRow As Long
Public iLastColumn As Long

Sub Interpolate()

    Dim iFirst As Long
    Dim iLast As Long

    'Find Last Row/Column of Data
    iLastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    iLastColumn = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'Interpolate across each row
    For iRowCounter = 2 To iLastRow
        If Cells(iRowCounter, 2) = "" Then
            'Do nothing if row is empty
        Else
            'Set up interpolation loop
            For iColumnCounter = 2 To iLastColumn - 1
                If Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter) <> "" Then
                    'Do Nothing if Column is populated
                Else
                    iFirst = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 1
                    iLast = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column

                End If
            Next iColumnCounter
        End If
    Next iRowCounter

End Sub
```

Screenshot of spreadsheet:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
Else
    iFirst = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 1
    iLast = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column
End If
```

Change it to:

```
Else
    iFirst = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByRowss, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 1
    iLast = Cells.Find("*", Cells(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column
End If
```

> Do your searching by `xlByRows`, instead of by `xlByColumns` to search horizontally across the row.

Comment: This worked!  I do not understand the search order, apparently.

Comment: It's alright, that happens. I initially had a totally different answer, then read more of your code to realize that you were doing what I initially said to do. :/  Glad that worked, click the check mark to accept it as the answer so others will know there's a working solution when they're searching.

Comment: It made me wait x minutes to accept the answer.  Don't worry, I clicked it.

Comment: ah,. forgot about that... :)